# Question regarding $K(a) \cong K[X]/(m(a,K))$ and the representation of elements in $L$ as linear combination

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

As I was reading about Algebra, the following came up:

It is often necessary, to write an Element $b \in K(a)$ of a simple extension $K(a)/K$ with $[K(a) : K]=n$, as linear combination
$b=k_0+k_1a+...+k_{n-1}a^{n-1}$, with $k_0,...,k_{n-1} \in K$.

To find a method to do so, one just needs to consider the lemma:

Let $L/K$ be a field extension.
If $a \in L$ is algebraic over $K$ with minimal polynomial $m(a,K)$, $deg (m(a,K))=n$, then
$K(a)=K[a] \cong K[X]/(m(a,K))$ and $n=[K(a) : K]$.

Now I am trying to find this method:

The Lemma tells us that
$K(a) \cong K[x]/(m(a,K))$, where $(m(a,K)):=\{p(x) m(a,K)(x) : p(x) \in K[x] \}$.

Now as far as I understand this if $p(a) \in K(a)$ the lemma syst that there exists some polynomial $R(x) \in K[x]/(m(a,K))$ such taht $ p(a)"="R(x)$.

If I take $P(a)$, look at $P(x)$ and divide $P(x)$ by $m(a,K)(x)$ I would get P(x)=m(a,K)(x)Q(x)+R(x).

Since $K[X]/(m(a,K))$ is an equivalence relation, I can choose a representative $v(x)$ for an equivalence class such that $deg(v(x))< deg(m(a,k)(x))$.

This means that  $m(a,K)(x)Q(x)+R(x)$ is in the same equivalence class as $R(x)$, and I can choose $R(x)$ as my representative.

This means that $P(a)$ can be written as $R(x)$.
But the statement above was that we would be able to write $R(x)$ als linear combination of $1,a,a^2,...,a^{n-1}$.
So my attempt seems to be wrong.
Could someone show me how this should work?

Comment: Analyse the isomorphism corresponding to $K(a)=K[a] \cong K[X]/(m(a,K))$.

Comment: Any member $b\in K(a) $ is given as a rational function $b=f(a) /g(a) $ with $f(x), g(x) \in K[x] $. One can use extended Euclidean algorithm to find $h(x) \in K[x] $ such that $1/g(a)=h(a)$ and then $b=f(a) h(a) $. Find remainder $r(x) $ when $f(x) h(x) $ is divided by $m(a, K)$ and then $b=r(a) $.